# Hoheisel's paper

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, paper-request, prime-gaps

Does anyone know a digital link to Hoheisel's paper: "Primzahlprobleme in der Analysis"?

It appeared in the 30's, published by the Berlin Academy. There seems to be no digital version.

Comment: More precisely, Guido Hoheisel, "Primzahlprobleme in der Analysis", Sitzberichte der Preußischen Akademie der Wissenschaften, Physik-Math Klasse 33 (1930), 580-588.  (Some citations give pages 3-11 - this could refer to the book, which is listed as held by several libraries at worldcat.org.)

Comment: if it is not forthcoming this week, I could get you a copy from our library next week.

Comment: I am sorry, I looked into the catalogue of Leiden University and only find the volumes up to 1929, quite frustrating.

Comment: Carlo B, many thanks for looking it up. It's weird that such a classic is so difficult to find. The original Hoheisel constant, is introduced in that paper...

Comment: Usually, the internet archive has many volumes of publications such as the "Preußischen Akademie...", but I wasn't able to locate the 1930 book

Comment: If anyone could provide a digital copy, it would be much apreciated. I'm working on the horizontal distribution of the cero's of the zeta function, and the Hoheisel paper is crucial, since the Selberg and Ingham results are largely based on it.